# Check checkbox from antoher activity

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I could check a checkBox in an  activity from another activity.

I'm making a homework app and I want to put a check next to the questions that have been completed.

So the first activity has a list of questions and next to them are unchecked boxes. When you click a question, the app takes you to the second activity. In the second activity, I want to check the box of the question that was completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharedPreferences for that. call this in the first activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.putBoolean("KEY", <your value>).apply();
```

and something similar in another activity:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
boolean isTicked = prefs.getBoolean("KEY", <default boolean value>);
```

where KEY can be anything, for example, your question's number

Comment: is there another way? I'm slightly confused, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: there are a lot of ways, try as suggested below. but the point of SharedPreferences is that it stores data in xml file, so you can save your question progress. 
what are you confused with, let me help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use intent and bundle logic for passing data between activities.(in most cases) 
In the first activity, whenever you are creating the second activity, you pass your data.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("checked",checkBox.isChecked());
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity you receive your data by using :

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
boolean finalChecked = receivedIntent.getExtras().getBoolean("checked");
//now you can apply your logic with finalChecked variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save checked check question to a bundle and pass it as extra to your second activity through intent and read it from that intent inside your second activity

In your first activity do something like this

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

     public static final String EXTRA_CHECKED_QUESTION = "Checked Question";

     // other codes here

     private void startSecondActivity() {
         String checkedQuestion = getCheckedQuestion(); // a method to get checked question
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_CHECKED_QUESTION, checkedQuestion);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

then in your second activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        // other codes

        String checkedQuestion = getIntent().getStringExtra(FirstActivity.EXTRA_CHECKED_QUESTION);
        // do whatever you want with checkQuestion
    } 
}
```

Please note that the string which you pass as first parameter to putExtra() method in FirstActivity, should be same as the string you are using with getStringExtra() to retrieve your extra in SecondActivity, otherwise you can not retrieve your passed extra in SecondActivity.

Also, I did not write these codes inside idea, so there might be syntax error

Read more about intent [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)